How do I get my app to request storage permission and access my device's storage? Flutter
I'm making an instagram clone on flutter and i'm trying to access the device's storage so the user can select images to post but the permission in the app settings is greyed out. I'm following a tutorial on youtube and and i followed the guy's code but mine doesn't work. I only get permission request on my emulator which runs android 11 but on my physical device that runs android 14, i don't get any permission requests and the permisiion is greyed out in the app settings. My code is below. (I already added the uses-permission to the android manifest)
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:photo_manager/photo_manager.dart';


class NewPostScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const NewPostScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<NewPostScreen> createState() => _NewPostScreenState();
}

class _NewPostScreenState extends State<NewPostScreen> {
  final List<Widget> _mediaList = [];
  final List<File> path = [];
  File? _file;
  int currentPage = 0;
  int? lastPage;

  _fetchNewMedia() async {
    lastPage = currentPage;
    final PermissionState ps = await PhotoManager.requestPermissionExtend();
    if (ps.isAuth) {
      List<AssetPathEntity> album =
          await PhotoManager.getAssetPathList(onlyAll: true);
      List<AssetEntity> media =
          await album[0].getAssetListPaged(page: currentPage, size: 60);

      for (var asset in media) {
        if (asset.type == AssetType.image) {
          final file = await asset.file;
          if (file != null) {
            path.add(File(file.path));
            _file = path[0];
          }
        }
      }
      List<Widget> temp = [];
      for (var asset in media) {
        temp.add(FutureBuilder(
            future: asset.thumbnailDataWithSize(const ThumbnailSize(
              200,
              200,
            )),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              print('Thumbnail data: ${snapshot.data}');
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                return Container(
                  child: Stack(
                    children: [
                      Positioned.fill(
                          child: Image.memory(
                        snapshot.data!,
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      ))
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              }
              return Container();
            }));
      }
      setState(() {
        _mediaList.addAll(temp);
        currentPage++;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _fetchNewMedia();
  }

  int indexx = 0;

  //@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).brightness == Brightness.light
            ? Colors.white
            : Colors.black,
        title: const Text(
          'New Post',
          style: TextStyle(
            //color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
            fontSize: 16,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
          ),
        ),
        toolbarHeight: 40,
        // elevation: 10,
        centerTitle: true,
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
      ),
      
      body: SafeArea(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                height: 410,
                child: GridView.builder(
                  gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                      crossAxisCount: 1,
                      mainAxisSpacing: 1,
                      crossAxisSpacing: 1),
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return _mediaList[indexx];
                  },
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                height: 40,
                //color: Colors.white,
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 10,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      'Recent',
                      style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              GridView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: _mediaList.length,
                gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                    crossAxisCount: 3, mainAxisSpacing: 1, crossAxisSpacing: 2),
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return GestureDetector(onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                      indexx = index;
                    });
                  }, child: _mediaList[index],
                  );
                },
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}



Does this answer your question? Storage Permission in Flutter

Hi, sadly it doesn't. I saw somewhere that newer android versions use something called Storage Access Framework instead of Read External Storage that was used for older versions. I don't know if that has something to do with my issue. I've been at this for days. Any suggestions are welcome.

Have you checked out the permissionpermission_handler plugin?

Add the Android extras for API 33 and API 34 as written here. After I added them, it started working properly.
Android 14 (API 34) extra configs
When targeting Android 14 (API level 34), the following extra configs needs to be added to the manifest:
<manifest>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VISUAL_USER_SELECTED" />  <!-- If you want to use the limited access feature. -->
</manifest>

Android 13 (API 33) extra configs
When targeting Android 13 (API level 33), the following extra configs needs to be added to the manifest:
<manifest>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" /> <!-- If you want to read images-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO" /> <!-- If you want to read videos-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO" /> <!-- If you want to read audio-->
</manifest>

